# Get favorited photos using vk API

Tags: api, vk

I want to download all my favorited photos from VK, but I couldn't find suitable method in documentation. User's faves are not album and it makes troubles. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use method `fave.getPhotos` to get pictures available [here](https://vk.com/fave?section=likes_photo).

Access `items` from response and extract picture link from fields `photo_807`, `photo_604`, `photo_130` or `photo_75` dependent on which size do you need.

You can download images using the links extracted.

https://vk.com/dev/fave.getPhotos?params[photo_sizes]=0&params[v]=5.67